# what is the wrong with this formula always get this error in the the pic attached

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, formula, formula-editor

excl formula

```
=IF(OR(B2:D2>10;E2>20);TRUE;FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: B2:D2>10 .... what are you trying to do here? Are you looking for all values larger than 10 or any one value being larger than 10?

Comment: This may be an array formula and you need to hit ctrl/shift/enter

Comment: Unless semi-colons are valid in other countries, the semi-colons should be commas.

Comment: i want ot get the result from this
 If the maximum number of any one fruit exceeds 10 pieces in an order,      
 or the total order exceeds 20 pieces (all fruit),    
 then mark it with "Special Order".     
Otherwise, mark it with "No".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't got Microsoft365 which means an array calculation within `OR()` needs to be CSE-confirmerd (Control+Shift+Enter). For Microsoft365 users this is done by default and your formula would actually work. You could now either use CSE-entering, or circumvent that using other methods to inspect a range of cells. For example using `MAX()`:

```
=IF(OR(MAX(B2:D2)>10,E2>20),"Special Order","No")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIF()

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(B2:D2;">"&10);E2>20);TRUE;FALSE)
```

But the if is not needed it the true output is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  Just use the first part:

```
=OR(COUNTIF(B2:D2;">"&10);E2>20)
```

Comment: Why not just `=OR(B3:D3>10,E3>20)`? I'm confused, as it works for me. Is this a non Microsoft365 answer?

Comment: maybe, I can never remember if that will work without the need of Ctrl-Shift-Enter or not.  I assumed it does and that is why I proposed the countif to avoid the need.

Comment: I get confused myself. But I suppose since it's an array that gets calculated here it would need to be CSE entered hence the error for OP I suppose. Good alternative..